# Graphql-Query-Qenerator how to create boolean query

Tags: javascript, class, graphql, graphql-js, graphql-java

I use graphql-query-generator to create queries more easily in my graphql requests.

link: https://github.com/IBM/graphql-query-generator

I have a mutation that deletes all users.

```
deleteAllUsers: Boolean

Type Details

The Boolean scalar type represents true or false.

scalar Boolean
```

I wrote a code like this by reading the graphql-query-generator document.

```
const { getRandomMutation } = require('ibm-graphql-query-generator');
const { buildSchema, print } = require('graphql');

const schema = `
  type Query {
    deleteAllUsers() 
  } 
`;

 const configuration = {
    depthProbability: 0.5,
    breadthProbability: 0.5,
 };

const { queryDocument } = getRandomMutation(buildSchema(schema), configuration);
  
const query = print(queryDocument);
```

After this line, it does not go to the bottom line and does not give an error.

```
const { queryDocument } = getRandomMutation(buildSchema(schema), configuration);
```

How do I create the deleteAllUsers mutation